# SQL Oracle object%rowtype dynamic

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, rowtype

I have an object which is a `ROWTYPE` from a table and need to recover some of the columns to an array list.

For example:

The `ROWTYPE` contents `Name1`, `Last_Name1`, `Id1`, `Adress1`...`Name25`,`Last_Name25`,`Id25`,`Adress25` in columns.

I need to know if I can recover them by a dynamic way with a loop to an array type like this:

Name(1-25),Last_Name(1-25),Id(1-25),Adress(1-25).

Answer (score 2):

Given a simplified example of the problem with the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id1, name1, id2, name2, id3, name3, id4, name4) AS
SELECT 1, 'N1', 2, 'N2', 3, 'N3', 4, 'N4' FROM DUAL;
```

I am assuming, that to get the `%ROWTYPE` variable, you are using something like:

```sql
DECLARE
  data TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO data FROM table_name FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1: ' || data.id1 || ', ' || data.name1);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('2: ' || data.id2 || ', ' || data.name2);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('3: ' || data.id3 || ', ' || data.name3);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('4: ' || data.id4 || ', ' || data.name4);
END;
/
```

Rather than trying to dynamically access the `%ROWTYPE` record, why do you not bypass the problem and separate the values in the `SELECT` statement using `UNPIVOT` in a cursor and then you can use `%ROWTYPE` on the cursor (rather than the table):

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT id, name
    FROM   (SELECT * FROM table_name FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
    UNPIVOT (
      (id, name)
      FOR idx IN (
        (id1, name1) AS 1,
        (id2, name2) AS 2,
        (id3, name3) AS 3,
        (id4, name4) AS 4
      )
    );
  
  TYPE cur_row_arr IS TABLE OF cur%ROWTYPE;
  rw  cur%ROWTYPE;
  arr cur_row_arr := cur_row_arr();
BEGIN
  OPEN cur;
  LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO rw;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    arr.EXTEND;
    arr(arr.COUNT) := rw;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur;
  
  FOR i IN 1 .. arr.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ': ' || arr(i).id || ', ' || arr(i).name );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=657a21ed747c1385b896e3cf098fd898)*

Comment: I need to dinamically access the rowtype because param is a rowtype object

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do it dynamically, just hard-code the values.

Given the simplified example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id1, name1, id2, name2, id3, name3, id4, name4) AS
SELECT 1, 'N1', 2, 'N2', 3, 'N3', 4, 'N4' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test(
  v_row IN TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE
)
IS
  TYPE details_type IS RECORD(
    id   TABLE_NAME.ID1%TYPE,
    name TABLE_NAME.NAME1%TYPE
  );

  TYPE details_tab_type IS TABLE OF details_type;

  details details_tab_type := details_tab_type();
BEGIN
  details.EXTEND(4);

  details(1) := details_type(v_row.id1, v_row.name1);
  details(2) := details_type(v_row.id2, v_row.name2);
  details(3) := details_type(v_row.id3, v_row.name3);
  details(4) := details_type(v_row.id4, v_row.name4);

  FOR i IN 1 .. details.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i || ': ' || details(i).id || ', ' || details(i).name);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*All you need to do is write the first assignment statement `details(1) := details_type(v_row.id1, v_row.name1);` and then copy-paste multiple copies and increment the numbers by 1 each time.*

Then you can call it using:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_row TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO v_row FROM table_name FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
  
  test(v_row);
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 1: 1, N1
> 2: 2, N2
> 3: 3, N3
> 4: 4, N4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b5279cef763bdcb1f19dbde15783c720)*